# Library to be used for copy feature in JS

Tags: node.js, copy-paste

I am building a web app in NodeJS and wanted to implement the copy feature. After some googling I found zero-clipboard. But it seemed to be using flash and quiet a heavy library. Are there any other alternatives? Any other libraries I can use?

By copy feature I mean like a button which says copy and that which copies the content of the input field or label to the clipboard.

Comment: Is it web application?

Comment: Yes let me update the same too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at clipboard js https://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/

We have used and its pretty neat. It does not use flash unlike zeroclipboard. Having said that clipboard js will not work on Safari.

Zeroclipboard is being maintained by github and they use the same for their copy feature too. And clipboardjs on the other hand is very recent and is written by zenrocha. Who has done a good job with the same.

You might also want to see [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Hope it helps!